# Inverse function -- need help

Tags: inverse

I'm a senior software developer but my math lessons are a bit rusty. I know the name of what I want, but not anymore how to compute it ;)

I've found (by myself with Grapher.app) a simple easing function (for transitions), that's a bijection from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$:

$$ f(x) = \frac{27}{4} \cdot \left( \left( \frac{2x}3 \right) ^2 - \left( \frac{2x}3 \right) ^3 \right) $$

Edit: in fact, after simplifying, it's as simple as:

$$ f(x) = 3 x^2 - 2 x^3 $$

The derivatives at $0$ and $1$ are both zero, so it's a perfect ease-in-out function that's easy to compute.

In order to start my transitions from anywhere between $0$ and $1$, I need $f^{-1}$, the inverse of this function, but I'm completely lost as to where to start... Would someone shed some light on my *oh-gosh-it-was-so-long-ago* math course?

Comment: normal form: y=function of x, 
inverse: x=function of y

Comment: It's simpler and easier to understand if you write $f(x)=3x^2-2x^3$.

Comment: Oh. My. Didn't even think of simplifying it. When I told you I'm rusty...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take your equation $3 x^2 - 2 x^3 = y$, substitute $x = X + 1/2$, multiply by $2$ and expand to get
$-4X^3 + 3 X = 2 y - 1$.  Now note that $\sin(3t) = - 4 \sin(t)^3 + 3 \sin(t)$.  Thus
a solution is
$X = \sin(t)$ where $\sin(3t) = 2y-1$, i.e.
$$ x = \sin\left(\frac{\arcsin(2y-1)}{3}\right) + 1/2 $$

Note that $0 \le x \le 1$ when $0 \le y \le 1$.

Comment: Wait wait wait... sinuses?

Comment: Okay, after re-reading it like ten times, it makes sense.

Comment: What I've always wondered (and that's where the beauty of maths comes from) is: where did you take the "substitute x = X + 1/2" from? I mean, did you just have to say "shazam" to find this?

Comment: Take $x = X + a$ and see what $a$ has to be to eliminate the $X^2$ term.

Answer (score 0):

The inverse function $g(y)$ satisfies $f[g(y)] = y$.  In this case:

$$\frac{27}{4} \cdot \left( \left( \frac{2g(y)}3 \right) ^2 - \left( \frac{2g(y)}3 \right) ^3 \right)  = y$$

Solve for $g(y)$ algebraically.  Might be tough because it's a cubic, but it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask to [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse%203x%5E2-2x%5E3):

```
1/2 (1+1/(1-2 x+2 sqrt(-x+x^2))^(1/3)+(1-2 x+2 sqrt(-x+x^2))^(1/3))
```

Or either you could implement the *bisection method* to solve $f(x) = y$. One should check, but it is possible that in this case the bisection method is faster than using the explicit formula for inverse.

Comment: Didn't even knew you could ask this to Wolfram. Thanks!

Comment: But notice that when $x \in (0,1)$, you're taking the square root of a negative number.  This is no accident: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis